# Radiometric calibration of WorldView-2 imagery using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, imagery, toa-calibration

I am attempting to work with worldview-2 imagery that I have downloaded and I am trying to radiometrically calibrate the raw imagery following the methodology outlined [here](https://dg-cms-uploads-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/document/file/104/Radiometric_Use_of_WorldView-2_Imagery.pdf). Since these are my first attempts, I wanted to make sure that I am doing it correctly.

In the first equation of page 9, one multiplies the image pixel value by the absolute radiometric calibration factor (Kband) and divides the result by the effective bandwidth (deltaK for each band). These values are contained in the .IMD file that comes with the downloaded imagery.

As an example, if a blue band pixel value is 4, and the .IMD data is

```
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_B
    ...
    absCalFactor = 1.783568e-02;
    effectiveBandwidth = 5.430000e-02;
    TDILevel = 10;
END_GROUP = BAND_B
```

Then the resulting value would be (4 * 1.783568e-02) / 5.430000e-02 = 1.31

Is this the correct interpretation of the data and the correct method of calibration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your understanding of the formula is correct.

```
TOA_radiance = DN * absCalFactor / effectiveBandwidth
```

This is the formula that you need.
However, as you likely already know, your example value of 4 is a rather unrealistic value. Values around 200 to 400 are more normal.